# Ripple - Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: app http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

Tags: requirejs, ripple

I'm using ripple chrome extension to test my mobile app. Why I got this error when test it with ripple? But if testing without it, everything works fine.

> Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: app
>
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but setting waitSeconds to 0 solved the problem for me. Found the solution here: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/628

It might also be an issue with Evernote Web Clipper, as reported here: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/876

**UPDATE:**

Try to update your requirejs config:

```
require.config({
  waitSeconds: 0,
  paths: {
    ...
  },
  shim: {
     ...
  }
```

Comment: This isn't a solution to the problem, setting waitSeconds to ill advised as it will mask any potential script loading problems that are occurring.

Comment: It works, thank you very much alancasagrande for the tip I set waitSeconds to zero an error was gone.
Regards

Comment: **waitSeconds**: The number of seconds to wait before giving up on loading a script. Setting it to 0 disables the timeout. The default is 7 seconds. [http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds]